# Permission problems with Google Sheet Script for ai SEO website audit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, seo, google-sheets-api, openai-api

I am trying to implement a code snippet from an article to help with some home / hobby SEO projects. The script should pull a website, run an audit, and make suggestions.
I run into a permission issue where Google is blocking the request. Everything is being done within my personal account, so I'm not sure where what permissions need to be modified (or how).
Code snippet is as follows:

```html
/**
 * Performs a content audit on the specified URL, using OpenAI's language model to provide a quality rating and actionable recommendations.
 *
 * @param {string} url The URL to audit.
 * @return The content quality rating and recommendations as provided by the language model.
 * @customfunction
 */
function performContentAudit(url) {
  // Get the active sheet and the range of values to audit
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // Loop through each URL in the range and perform an audit
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === url) { // check if this is the URL we want to audit
      var prompt = "I would like you to audit content ...: " + url;

      // Call the OpenAI API to perform the audit
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions", {
        'method': 'post',
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer openai API KEY '
        },
        'payload': JSON.stringify({
          'prompt': prompt,
          'temperature': 0.5,
          'max_tokens': 1024
        })
      });

      // Parse the API response and get the audit results
      var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      var answer = json.choices[0].text;

      // Return the audit results
      return answer;
    }
  }

  // Return an error message if the specified URL was not found
  return "Error: URL not found in sheet";
}
```

I'm prompted to allow permissions but then receive the error:

> This app is blocked
> This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Update with modified code:

Comment: Hey @ADH did the below work?

Comment: @YancyGodoy - worked very well. On to the next set of issues!

Answer (score 1):

According to similar cases, creating a new project in your Google Cloud console and assign the project ID to the Apps Script project allows you to authorize without issues.

The steps are the following:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. [Create a new project](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate)
3. Go to the ‘OAuth Consent Screen’ on the sidebar menu.

   - Configure the project settings, for free Gmail accounts, select the ‘external’ user type.
   - Set the `App name`, `User support email` and `Developer contact information`.
   - Save and continue.
4. Go to the sidebar menu and go to `APIs & Services` > `Library`, search for Drive API, Sheets API and enable both services.
5. Click the 3 dots on the top right and select "Project settings", copy the `Project number`.
6. Go back to your Apps Script project, go to the sidebar menu and go to `Project Settings`.
7. Go to the `Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project` section and insert the project number from step (5).
8. Finally run the script again, you'll be asked to authorize and this time it should let you continue without issues.

You can see more detailed steps [here](https://aimanfikri.com/2022/05/09/this-app-is-blocked-error-on-google-apps-script-solution/).

Comment: Thanks, Lorena! I am past the permission issues, as your recommendation worked perfectly. I am on to the next set of issues.